# haproxy, is it impossible to monitor the http total request time?

Tags: proxy, monitoring, haproxy, response-time

using haproxy HTTP logs with http-server-close of keep-alives the time counters in the logs (TR, Tt...) are based on the beginning of the TCP connection. Which means only the first request, with cookie status *NI (--NI) has timers corresponding to the time the HTTP request took.

The following ones will be from the beginning of the TCP connection (idles times + preceding request times).

Is there a way to bypass this haproxy behaviour without turning keepalive or http-server-close off, or am I forced to change this configuration, or to add a proxy in front of haproxy..?

---

In the end is there a way to get the total response time for an HTTP request, and not the time since the beginning of the TCP ?

Answer (score 0):

```
time curl -v http://www.google.com http://www.google.com
```

this will use keep alives, and not open a new TCP connection for ever request (as long as your web server support keepalives).

- Connection #0 to host [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) left intact
- Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Maybe this will give you a start.

Curl has quite good options for tracing connect times too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl

So this might give you exactly what you want.

Good Luck!

Comment: the thing is I want to have the total response time for each request made to my haproxy, from my haproxy POV, not from one client. in order to obtain the total average response-time. the issue is the response time timer in haproxy count from the opening of the tcp, not the beginning of the http request, even in http-log mode.

Comment: I'm not sure i totally understand, you said 'for each request made to my haproxy, from my haproxy POV,' so you have two HA-PROXYS? maybe a digram could make clearer what exactly you are trying to measure, the end points, and what's inbetwen.

Comment: No there is only one haproxy, my bad. What I wanted to mean is I want the response-time from the server (my haproxy) point of view, not from a curl client side.

Answer (score 0):

After refining what you meant, i believe you want to find out exactly what ha-proxy is actually doing, rather than generating benchmarking test from a client using curl and ab (apache bench).

Ha proxy comes with on stats page, which can give you lots of parameters. This might just have what you need.

https://www.haproxy.com/blog/exploring-the-haproxy-stats-page/

You can retrieve the stats that haproxy is generating. You should be interested in

```
Response time   

The server response time in milliseconds, averaged over the last 1024 successful connections.
```

Good Luck!